# How to integrate flowtype with spacemacs

Tags: flowtype, spacemacs

I'm [spacemacs](http://spacemacs.org/) fan. I want to use [Facebook Flow](http://www.flowtype.org) but I have not idea how to integrate it with spacemacs. I'm using flow with `nuclide` but I need to relearn everything to be productive. There is [this script](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/flow-types.el) on `flow` repository to use it with emacs. I need a guide for how to use it within spacemacs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used Bodil's flow flycheck config here: https://github.com/bodil/emacs.d/blob/d28264cf072bb8a62459a48813d0cb30804b4f5b/bodil/bodil-js.el#L121-L154

I made it work with spacemacs's `react-mode` and default eslint flychecker by adding the following to my `dotspacemacs/user-config` (https://github.com/saltycrane/.spacemacs.d/blob/9d985ace9251529c2b8d7857e2ec9835b103084c/init.el#L383-L414):

```
;; Flow (JS) flycheck config (http://flowtype.org)
;; from https://github.com/bodil/emacs.d/blob/master/bodil/bodil-js.el
(require 'f)
(require 'json)
(require 'flycheck)

(defun flycheck-parse-flow (output checker buffer)
  (let ((json-array-type 'list))
    (let ((o (json-read-from-string output)))
      (mapcar #'(lambda (errp)
                  (let ((err (cadr (assoc 'message errp))))
                    (flycheck-error-new
                     :line (cdr (assoc 'line err))
                     :column (cdr (assoc 'start err))
                     :level 'error
                     :message (cdr (assoc 'descr err))
                     :filename (f-relative
                                (cdr (assoc 'path err))
                                (f-dirname (file-truename
                                            (buffer-file-name))))
                     :buffer buffer
                     :checker checker)))
              (cdr (assoc 'errors o))))))

(flycheck-define-checker javascript-flow
  "Javascript type checking using Flow."
  :command ("flow" "--json" source-original)
  :error-parser flycheck-parse-flow
  :modes react-mode
  :next-checkers ((error . javascript-eslint))
  )
(add-to-list 'flycheck-checkers 'javascript-flow)
```

Also be sure the Flow command line tool is installed. Install it like this:

```
npm install -g flow-bin
```

I think Bodil intended to make the messages short, but I would like to have flycheck display more verbose messages. If anyone knows how to do that, I'd appreciate it.

EDIT 2016-08-12: the original version I posted gave a `Symbol's function definition is void: flycheck-define-checker` error on initial load. I updated the code above to add a `require 'flycheck` to get rid of that error.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by saltycrane worked fine for me. Thanks! The solution gives a very short error messages as he points out. I have improved the error messages to be more verbose and look more like the output from flow cli output.

A note to new users who wants to use this script is to make sure you edit it to use the correct mode in `flycheck-define-checker` at the bottom. I use this in `js2-mode`, and saltycrane uses `react-mode`. Edit it to use whatever you are using.

```
(require 'f)
(require 'json)
(require 'flycheck)
(defun flycheck-parse-flow (output checker buffer)
  (let ((json-array-type 'list))
    (let ((o (json-read-from-string output)))
      (mapcar #'(lambda (errp)
                  (let ((err (cadr (assoc 'message errp)))
                        (err2 (cadr (cdr (assoc 'message errp)))))
                    (flycheck-error-new
                     :line (cdr (assoc 'line err))
                     :column (cdr (assoc 'start err))
                     :level 'error
                     :message (concat (cdr (assoc 'descr err)) ". " (cdr (assoc 'descr err2)))
                     :filename (f-relative
                                (cdr (assoc 'path err))
                                (f-dirname (file-truename
                                            (buffer-file-name))))
                     :buffer buffer
                     :checker checker)))
              (cdr (assoc 'errors o))))))

(flycheck-define-checker javascript-flow
  "Static type checking using Flow."
  :command ("flow" "--json" source-original)
  :error-parser flycheck-parse-flow
  :modes js2-mode)
(add-to-list 'flycheck-checkers 'javascript-flow)
```